# Bottom-aligned header contents are bugging me

Tags: bug, design

The new updates are probably still rolling out for the SE sites but I noticed this issue only on UX StackExchange.

The second header has the logo and the navigation items aligned to the bottom which is really bugging me. If that's done for some specific reason then it's fine but I feel like it should be vertically aligned to the center OR have a bottom hr to show the active tab.

[image: UX SE Header]